# LINQ not executed correctly

Tags: c#, linq

I have this piece of code:

```
DataTable dtDataTable = …;
var rows = dtDataTable.AsEnumerable();
var test = rows.Select(x => x["id"]).Distinct().Count() != rows.Count();
if (test)
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");
    return false;
}
```

Problem: if test should be true, the code in the `if` statement does not get executed. I cannot seem to debug this (it just continues running my code).

I think it may have to do something with deferred/immediate execution, but I can't find a solution (I've tried adding `.ToList()` after the `select` already).

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `rows` and can you give some data? Also, you don't need to `Select` first...

Comment: Why use `x["id"]`? What is `rows`?

Comment: Deferred execution does not seem to be an issue here, as `test` is assigned immediately. What makes you think that `test` becomes true?

Comment: Yup, that's correct. rows = dtDataTable.AsEnumerable();

Comment: Error 2 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First i thought that `Dictinct` would compare by reference since the `DataRow` indexer returns an `Object` instead of an `int`. So i suggested to use the strongly typed `Field` extension method. But that was not the reason for your issue.

So until you don't know the reason i suggest you a different (more efficient) approach to check if all ID's are unique:

```
var ids = rows.Select(r => r.Field<int>("ID"));
var duplicateIdChecker = new HashSet<int>();
bool isIdUnique = ids.All(duplicateIdChecker.Add);
```

Comment: To be clear, `Distinct<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` - it's only comparing by reference because the `T` here is `object`.

Comment: EDIT: nvm, give me a sec :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: i've tested it, it seems that i was on the wrong track. It should also work with the indexer which returns an `Object`.

Comment: @Bv202: i have edited my answer to provide a different approach. Try that.

Comment: @TimSchmelter If the correct comparer was being used (because the underlying type was something that didn't use reference equality), then the only remaining cause for the issue is it contains duplicates. If the list was really unique based on the `Distinct` call, it would match the `rows.Count()` call too.

Comment: I don't get it. Even that doesn't seem to work, even thouh your solutions sound logical. I cannot provide any more information as I simple do not have more - putting a breakpoint at this code to debug doesnt work - the code simply continues for some reason...

Comment: @Bv202 Take it you've compiled in debug mode? My guess is your list is not unique and thus doesn't display the message box or return. Can't help any more on the failing breakpoint stuff.

Comment: @Bv202: so are you sure that there are duplicates? Have a look at the debuggers quick watch window. There is a dataset visualizer(the loupe).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: i'm still interested in the reason why my first thought was not the reason. I thought that `Object.Equals` would be used because of the unboxing. **Edit** I think it's because [`private static EqualityComparer<T> CreateComparer()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs,542680fa5b2d828d) in [`EqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses some tricks to get the correct comparer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Interesting find.

Comment: I'll look into this tomorrow as it seems I have more issues with VS. Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter is there a significant improvement using `Field<int>(...)` as opposed to `Convert.ToInt32(...)`?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff: `Field` also needs to unbox the object, but it has it's benefits since it supports nullable types: `int? idWhichCanBeNull=row.Field<int?>("ID");`. The `Convert.To...` methods are also a little bit cumbersome. The generic `Field` method can be modified easily(f.e. if you need to copy/paste code and change the type from int to DateTime).

Answer (score 1):

Tried your code with some test data, also wrote my piece of code for the same task, everything is working. So I guess that Ids are not comparing correctly

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("id");
dt.Columns.Add("desc");

var dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = 1;
dr[1] = "prova1";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = 1;
dr[1] = "prova2";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = 2;
dr[1] = "prova3";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

var rows = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>();
var test = (rows.Select(row => row["id"]).Distinct().Count() != rows.Count());    
Console.WriteLine(test);

var rows1 = dt.AsEnumerable();
test = rows.Select(x => x["id"]).Distinct().Count() != rows.Count();
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Comment: Something weird is going on in my code - I can't seem to debug things anymore. I'll look into this tomorrow because you're right: this should work indeed...